# Input button hide based url

Tags: php, url, button, input, hide

I am trying to hide an input button hide when the specific URL `product_catalog.php?c=12` is loaded.

Here is my button code in `product_catalog.php`:

```
echo "<INPUT type=\"text\" name=\"qty\" size=2 value=\"1\" class=\"text-pc\"><span class=\"small2\">kpl</span>&nbsp;";
echo "<INPUT type=\"submit\" name=\"add\" value=\"&nbsp;\" id=\"lisaa\" class=\"add-to-basket\">";
```

How do I hide it if the user is browsing `product_catalog.php?c=12`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple `if` statement to check if `$_GET['c']` is not equal to `12`:

```
if($_GET['c'] != '12') {
  // put your echo statements here.
}
```

---

Note that this is a fairly simple question about a base control structure of PHP. You might want to learn more about control structures by reading the PHP Manual before continuing with your project.

**Concepts touched in this answer:**

> [PHP Manual: Control Structures](http://php.net/control-structures.intro)
> [PHP Manual: if](http://php.net/if)
> [PHP Manual: Superglobals](http://php.net/variables.superglobals)